# How do I use variables in bash to output to a file and to a mail body with sendmail

Tags: bash, email, plesk

The idea is to automate WordPress installs via Plesk.

I've got Plesk setup with a cronjob to download the latest.tar.gz from wordpress.com and extract it every morning and now I'm trying to get the database creation side of things automated.

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash/

#To whoever is working on this
#this script simply sets up the DATABASE for the new domain added to the server
#it then logs it, mails the details and clears the log


genpasswd() {
 local pass=`cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd "[:punct:]" | head -c 2`
    echo "$pass"
}

echo $NEW_DOMAIN_NAME >> /usr/games/newdomain.txt
DOMAINNAME=`echo $NEW_DOMAIN_NAME | grep -oE '/[^/]+' | cut -c6- | rev | cut -c4- | rev`
rndChr=$(genpasswd)

CHAR2=${$DOMAINNAME:1:1}
CHAR4=${$DOMAINNAME:3:1}

echo $CHAR2$CHAR4 >> /usr/games/passChar.txt

#get our db stuff
DATABASENAME='exsite_'$DOMAINNAME
DATABASEUSER='exsite_'$DOMAINNAME
DATABASEPASS='[exSite_'$CHAR2$rndChr$CHAR4']'


#create our mail content
CONTENTS="<strong>New MySQL Database created</strong> - <i>see the login details below.<i><p><strong>dbname</strong>    $DATABASENAME<br><strong>dbuser</strong>    $DATABASEUSER<br><strong>dbpass<strong> $DATABASEPASS"

#log it
echo -e $CONTENTS > /usr/games/dbLog.txt


#mail it
sendMail() {
cat << 'EOF' - /usr/games/dbLog.txt | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
To: servers@exsite.ie
From: Enterprise
Reply-to: alex@exsite.ie
Subject: [DB Info] for $NEW_DOMAIN_NAME on enterprise.exsite.co
Content-Type: text/html

EOF

printf "STATUS: Mail sent!"

}

if [[ $(sendMail) ]]
then 
    printf "STATUS: Doing mail thing!"
else
    printf "STATUS: MAIL-FAIL!!"
fi

#clear dbLog.txt
exit
```

Two problems are occuring but I don't understand why;

The CHAR2 and CHAR4 variables don't seem to pick up the 2nd and 4th characters of $DOMAINNAME - they just output empty into passChat.txt

$NEW_DOMAIN_NAME goes to newdomain.txt but then the next line where I try to return just the 2nd level domain seems to fail. It was working at an earlier point but it's not now. I hadn't changed that part though.

Comment: The syntax for the more "advanced" parameter substitution does NOT include the dollar **inside** the braces ([ref](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion))-- `CHAR2=${DOMAINNAME:1:1}`

Comment: What does `$NEW_DOMAIN_NAME` look like? I can't really grok what that grep|cut|rev|... line is supposed to do

Comment: $NEW_DOMAIN_NAME is supposed to be mydomain.com and the CHAR2=${DOMAINNAME:1:1} should get me the 2nd character, so in this case, should hold the character 'y' from 'mydomain.com' and CHAR4 should hold 'o'

Comment: oh and the grep|cut|rev is supposed to strip the www. and the .com from the domain name although they're coming through now without www. so maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to get "mydomain" whether you are given any of: "mydomain.com", "www.mydomain.com", "mail.secure.mydomain.com", ...

```
get_domain_name() {
    local IFS=.
    set -- $1
    local n=$(($# - 1))
    echo ${!n}
}

get_domain foo.bar.baz.qux
```

```
baz
```

---

The proper way to check the results of your `sendmail` function is with a lot less syntax:

```
if sendmail
then echo OK
else echo uh oh
fi
```

`if` checks the exit status of a command. Note that `[[` is a bash builtin command (that requires its last argument to be `]]`) -- at a bash prompt, type `help [[ if`

---

In your `sendmail` function, you use `cat << 'EOF'` -- that effectively single-quotes the entire here-doc. Any variables will **not** be substituted.

You appear to want to contatenate the heredoc, then stdin, then a named file, and then pipe all that to sendmail. You'll need a bit more syntax to do it: use the `{ grouping }` braces to concatenate the info, then pipe the result to sendmail

```
sendMail() {
    {
        cat <<- HEADERS
            To: servers@exsite.ie
            From: Enterprise
            Reply-to: alex@exsite.ie
            Subject: [DB Info] for $NEW_DOMAIN_NAME on enterprise.exsite.co
            Content-Type: text/html

            HEADERS
        cat -
        cat /usr/bin/games/dbLog.txt
    } | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t && echo "STATUS: Mail sent!"
}
```

Note here I used a heredoc with `<<-` to allow the use of leading tabs to indent document. bash is strict about only leading tabs, not spaces, so be careful about that.

---

Are you aware that `printf` does not append a newline to the outputted string? All your messages are going to be squished together on one line.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I will make the appropriate changes you've suggested and see where that gets me.

Comment: This happens when I do your sendmail function and I can't figure out what the error means? You have the blank line after the terminating HEADER? Why doesn't it see that as the EOF?


`newDB.sh: line 66: warning: here-document at line 46 delimited`     `by end-of-file (wanted `HEADERS')`
`newDB.sh: line 67: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: Make sure there are *only tab characters* before the terminating HEADERS.

Comment: I rarely use `<<-` just for this potential problem. It's hard to maintain only tabs. My vim setup uses spaces for indentation so it's extra effort to ensure tabs.

Comment: The only thing now is that the get domains function doesn't seem to work - it just returned an empty string? I just rewrote my grep|rev|cut|rev command for now but I realized it only works for .com domains (or any 3 letter tlds) but not for the likes or .ie or .co.uk

Still it's good enough for now :) Thanks again!